# REgULAR expression validation in angular

Tags: angularjs

can i validate the string in angular?

please see the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

[ngPattern](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern) is the easiest way of doing this.

You can pass either a regex literal or a regex string to ngPattern and it will validate the input using that regex.

Comment: donno how to use regular expression.. can i get any help from you to write literal ?